# Cakephp Local session logic

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have a simple if checking for a customer_id in the session.

```
<?php if($this->Session->read('customer_id')){ ?>
    <?php echo $this->element('watchlist'); ?>      
<? } else { ?>
    <?php echo $this->element('recently_sold'); ?>              
<?php } ?>
```

It's very simple, but when I visit the page, the customer_id is null, and neither of the elements show up.  When I login, BOTH the elements are displayed.  Something is really strange with the logic here and I'm not sure where to start.  I tried checked for null and using is_numeric, but still the same results.  Has anyone had any issues with sessions on their local environment like this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're constantly opening and closing your PHP tags? You're also using a short-tag on the third-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your PHP set-up recognise the PHP **short tags** `<? ... ?>` as opposed to `<?php ... ?>` ?

If it doesn't then your `} else {` statement will not be recognized as PHP and so both echo's will happen when the if-statement is true (and you should see the "<? } else { ?>" printed out as text in your source code if you look carefully).

Like @Chris Hendy says above it's confusing to keep opening and closing PHP tags for no reason.

Short tags should not be used as they are a server setting and most servers do not have them on by default. From PHP 5.4 short tags are on a switch with the difference that the "echo short tag "

Comment: @ChrisHendry was right, that was the issue.  php wasn't setup to read short tags.  I read somewhere that php 5.4 fixed this or something?

Comment: @DevatoTech short tags should not be used as they are a server setting and most servers do not have them on by default. From PHP 5.4 short tags are on a switch with the difference that the "echo short tag "<?= " is independent than the other. The best to do in my opinion is NOT to use short tags, use long opening and closing tags instead and use the "echo short tag" ("<?=") where applicable. It is very handly for inline echo statements.